# how to create Operating System in C?

Tags: c, operating-system

I love programming in C. And I want to create an O.S using C. BUt I've no idea from where to begin? Some suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: You can start by doing some research with your favorite search engine. That's too broad.

Comment: Writing an OS is dissertation-level stuff.

Comment: @DanFarrell My senior did it as an undergrad project!

Comment: Then you have a great place to start - with his code.  You might also be interested in looking at minix.  http://www.minix3.org/

Comment: thanX, If I had contacted him, would I post a question here?!

Comment: @Roma it's not dissertation level software but it's also not something you can post a question on and expect to receive a useful answer. There are simply too many facets to cover, not only operating system concepts (of which there are many) but hardware concepts as well (i/o devices of different types, memory management hardware, interrupt control, DMA, among others).

Answer (score 3):

Try reading [Modern Operating Systems](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0136006639) for an overview of what you're in for.

[image]

Comment: One of best books for OS, I have read entire 2 years before.